# How to append (not import) csv to table in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, append

I have existing table in database, I want to add more data to this table, but I can only import from the popped up window shown below.

I am pulling data from server, it requires permission to import data if I import through SQL queries.

How can I solve this problem? I appreciate every experienced answer!

[image]

Comment: This method will append data and not over write.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

The picture show above is the interface when you right click the table, choose import.
It will append, and not overwrite. A little bit tricky.